# Yii2 htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: yii, yii2

I am using **DetailView** widget, and I am trying to write custom function as value, but I keep getting this error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

This is the code:

```
[
                'label' => 'Keys',
                'value' => function($model, $key, $inde){

                    if(!empty($model->keys))
                        return '<strong>User don\'t have any key at the moment.</strong>';

                    $keys = '';
                    foreach($model->keys as $key):

                        $keys .= '<strong>' . $key->key . '</strong>';

                    endforeach;

                    return $keys;

                }
            ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you add `'format' => 'raw'`, to your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DetailView `value` don't accept anonymous function (differently respect grdiView) .. in this case you can set the related value using a call to a normal function  .. remember that in DetailView you work directly to $model and not on a $dataProvider content

then  you can use a function

```
function myFunction($model, $key, $inde){

                if(!empty($model->keys))
                    return '<strong>User don\'t have any key at the moment.</strong>';

                $keys = '';
                foreach($model->keys as $key):

                    $keys .= '<strong>' . $key->key . '</strong>';

                endforeach;

                return $keys;
   }
```

or simple assign the result to a var

and in detail view attribute  call the function or assigne the var directly

```
 [
            'label' => 'Keys',
            'value' => myFunction($model, $key, $inde),
```

Answer (score 1):

add `'format' => 'html'`

```
[
            'label' => 'Keys',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => function($model, $key, $inde){

                if(!empty($model->keys))
                    return '<strong>User don\'t have any key at the moment.</strong>';

                $keys = '';
                foreach($model->keys as $key):

                    $keys .= '<strong>' . $key->key . '</strong>';

                endforeach;

                return $keys;

            }
],
```